# c# mysqlDb connection in separate class

Tags: c#, mysql, class

I have a problem. 
The thing is I want to use same db connection project-wide. 
I think that I need to create a separate class for it. 
What I want: 
I want something like Sqliteconnection component, but for MYSQL. 
A class that handles the connection to mysql database, and accessible from everywhere in the code. 
Googled this kind of stuff, used search here-no luck.
I am pretty new to c#, so I would very appreciate your help!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: I have that already,but this connector does not provide a VS component like devart sqlite does. Or i'm missing something,i can't find a component in VS(C#). That's why i'm asking for help here.

Comment: What to you mean component? You were looking for common classes - it does have MySqlConnection, MySqlCommand, MySqlDataReader etc.. all the common .NET classes for DB access

Comment: I'm sorry,english is not my first language. It's a thing like TextBox,label.  Here,i took a screenshot of what i meant -------http://habrastorage.org/storage3/9b9/382/c5c/9b9382c5cd92b008793cf71bd3a96af3.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a class for creating a db connection for sql server, you'll have to make the proper changes for Mysql;

```
public class SQLServer
{   
    SqlConnection myConnection = null;
    SqlCommand myCommand = null;
    /// <summary>
    /// Connection information should be stored in the appp.conf
    /// Example:
    /// <add name="SQLConnection" connectionString="Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;
    ///   Integrated Security="True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    /// </summary>
    public SQLServer()
    {
      string myConfig = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnection"].ConnectionString;
      myConnection = new SqlConnection(myConfig);
      myConnection.Open();
    }

    //Executes sql query and returns datareader     
    public SqlDataReader NewReader(string sSQL)
    {
      myCommand = new SqlCommand(sSQL, myConnection);
      SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
      return myReader;
    }

    //Execute sql statement and returns nothing usefull for inserts and updates
    public void Execute(string SQL)
    {
      Execute(SQL, false);
    }
 }
```

To use the class;

```
SQLServer myClass = new SQLServer();
SqlDataReader myReader = myClass.NewReader("SQL Syntax");
while (myReader.Read())
{
  MessageBox.Show(myReader["some_field"].ToString())
}
```

I've omitted any error handling, and closing connections, make sure you do that to avoid problems.

Comment: Thank you very much,will work on it.